# FaceLivenessDetector websocket failed to connect on localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js

I'm using AWS FaceLivenessDetector component which loading perfect, code is as follow

```
<FaceLivenessDetector
 sessionId={createLivenessApiData.SessionId}
 region="us-east-2"
 onAnalysisComplete={handleAnalysisComplete}
 onError={(error) => console.log(error, "error")}
/>
```

But as I'm running this on localhost I'm facing issue for websocket connection and then getting server error.

[image]

Is there any issue using localhost on http or there is some other issue.